# Flutter Provider, where to place a function call to load data from firestore database

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, state-management

I'm currently working on an app and I want to get some data of a user's friends. Ideally, after sign in, this information is loaded up onto the screen for viewing.

I initially made my function call to do this within the "build" method of my HomeScreen, but this caused an infinite loop as the function call ended with "notifyListeners()".

That being said, where should I place my call to avoid a loop, while still having the UI update once the data has been fetched from the database?

Comment: can you please add the code you have got so far to the question?

Comment: if you using statefull widget , initState is the right place to calling any api

Comment: You could also fetch data in the `Provider`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [`FutureBuilder` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), which provides great functionality to load async data and show the result once available. While the data is loading, or if your code runs into an error, you can show a different widget. Essentially it works like this:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _yourFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        // Return loading indicator
        return Container();
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          // Return error
          return Container();
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // Data loaded => use snapshot.data to access it
          return Container();
        }
  }
})
```

I would not recommend to load data during `initState()`, since this method cannot be async and thus, you cannot await your result.

I hope that helps.